# VS2008 Setup Project - No Repair Option

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-project

Is there anyway to disable the repair option so that if a user runs the msi again it automatically uninstalls without prompting for Repair/Remove options?

Edit: This is for a controlled corporate environment and has been passed down as a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your edit, I'll try to give a guess, though I don't really know if it's possible just with an msi file.  A tool "orca" can be downloaded from Microsoft (unrelated to "orcas" which was code name for a Visual Studio version).  "Orca" can edit some properties of msi files, so that would be one place I'd look for a possibility of disabling a repair option.

Another guess is that you might be able to insert a custom action early enough.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that really an unfriendly thing to do? Shouldn't the user get to decide whether they want a repair or an uninstall? Write a separate uninstall program if you want to provide an uninstaller with one less click.